# Capacitor in a circuit with uneven charges

Tags: capacitor

Is it possible in a circuit that a capacitor has uneven charges on its plates?
I mean Q1 is not equal to -Q2 in a certain instant of time.

Comment: Yes, at very high frequencies where the wavelength of the signal is getting to within a ball-park of the distances involved.

Comment: Basically, yes on a timescale close to the speed of light. Pump charge in one side, its electric field has to propagate at the speed of light through the dielectric, which reduces as 1/sqrt(dielectric constant).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! How can I close this topic?

Answer (score 0):

From the comnents of Andy aka and Brian Drummond:
Yes, when the signal's wavelength has same or smaller magnitude as the physical size of the capacitor.